# C#: Enable-Migrations without building other projects

Tags: c#, migration, project, datamodel

So I need to refactor my domain model which I keep in a subproject of its own.  During this refactor, my Startup App clearly isn't going to compile or build.  But if that main app doesn't build, I can't make any changes concerning my Migrations and Datamodel.

My question is "Is there a way I can make the DataModel project ignore the fact that they other projects won't build, and that it should continue with it's business"?

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to set the project I am working on to the  "Starup Project"  Once that is done, it doesn't worry about building the other annoyances.